# How to give the output of the first query(which has two values) as the input to the second?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, subquery

i get 2 names as the output of the first query....
eg: paul,peter
now this should be the input for the second query,
which has to display paul's and peter's email ids....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For nested queries I would strongly recommend `WITH` clause. It makes long complex queries order of magnitude easier to understand / construct / modify:

```
WITH 
   w_users AS( -- you can name it whatever you want
      SELECT id
        FROM users
       WHERE < long condition here >
   ),
   w_other_subquery AS(
      ...
   )
SELECT email_id
  FROM ...
 WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM w_users)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use like this

LIKE

```
SELECT USER_ID,EMAIL_ID FROM USERS where user_id IN 
(SELECT PRODUCT_MEMBERS FROM PRODUCT WHERE PRODUCT_NAME='ICP/RAA');
```

Just use the IN clause '=' is used for matching one result

Answer (score 1):

You can use In Command to get result
ex:

```
SELECT  email FROM tableName WHERE (Name IN ('paul', 'peter'))
```

Comment: thanks, but "paul n peter" are just examples of the output, it may vary each time....

Comment: get all name in variables and pass as parameter to IN Function

Comment: SELECT USER_ID,EMAIL_ID FROM USERS where user_id =
(SELECT PRODUCT_MEMBERS FROM PRODUCT
WHERE PRODUCT_NAME='ICP/RAA');

This is the actual query.... i dont know how to get them as variables....
the output of the corelated query is.... "sri,vik"
now i have to take both as input for the outer query and display their email ids